# Kestrel guide/tutorial/documentation?

Tags: java, kestrel

I was trying see how Kestrel works but I'm having some difficulties even to find a working example in Java using it as a library.

Do someone has a link or can help me on the set up of a queue?

I've found [this](https://gist.github.com/784413) but it doesn't work on the last release.. : /

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found this link which shows a client created using PHP. I was able to use this as a basis for creating a Java client: http://blog.shupp.org/2011/05/07/getting-started-with-kestrel-from-a-php-application/

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;

public class KestrelClient {
    private MemcachedClient client = null;
    private String kestrelHost = null;
    private int kestrelPort = -1;

    public KestrelClient(final String kestrelHost, final int kestrelPort)
    {
        this.kestrelHost = kestrelHost;
        this.kestrelPort = kestrelPort;

        try
        {
            this.client = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress(this.kestrelHost, this.kestrelPort));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean set(final String queueName, final int expiration, final Object data)
    {
        Future<Boolean> setFuture = this.client.set(queueName, expiration, data);

        try
        {
            return setFuture.get().booleanValue();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Object reliableRead(final String queueName, final int timeout)
    {
        Object object = this.client.get(queueName + "/close/open/t=" + timeout);
        closeReliableRead(queueName);
        return object;
    }

    public void closeReliableRead(final String queueName)
    {
        this.client.get(queueName + "/close");
    }

    public void abortReliableRead(final String queueName)
    {
        this.client.get(queueName + "/abort");
    }
}
```

It's not perfect but it should get you started. (Dependency on spymemcached.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was initially using the xmemcached client but then found it easier to use with a simple wrapper around it. That wrapper became jestrel, which is available here under an Apache license:

https://github.com/cobbzilla/jestrel

I designed the jestrel API for extreme simplicity. It's been tested in production environments and performs well. Give it a try and let me know what you think.